# Window Pop-up Import/Export Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have done an import and export script which imports/exports a file with all current spawned objects and their XYZ coordinates. However, there's still an issue. What I am doing now when exporting is saving the file in "Application.persistentDataPath" automatically, however I am looking forward to have a window pops-up and requests you where to save the file on your PC and same for importing.

Here's the code of importing and exporting:

```cs
public void WriteString(string message)
{
    //    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+display.text+".txt";
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/txt.txt";
    //Write some text to the test.txt file
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    writer.WriteLine(message);
    writer.Close();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

    //Print the text from the file
    Debug.Log(reader.ReadToEnd());
    reader.Close();
}
```

```cs
public void ReadString()
{
    // string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+display.text+".txt";
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/txt.txt";
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    string line = "";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a builtin editor utility for this, called `EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel` See the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel.html).

For importing use [`EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html).

Note that these methods will block until the user selects a path and return that path when they did so. If the action is cancelled, an empty string is returned.